# calling function in for and foreach loop failing in PHP

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have an array on which I am iterating using for loop. The array has URL at each element that is needed to be passed as argument to a function.

When I call the function during iteration, loop stops after first iteration and does not proceed over entire array.

When I try to echo out only the value in array and does not call function in loop then it works fine.

This is the same issue if I use foreach loop. Please help.

Here is my code

```
echo '<ol>';
for($i=0; $i < count($watchList); $i++){
    saveProduct(getProductDetail($watchList[$i]));
    echo ' <li>Product Saved '. $watchList[$i] .'</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: What is the value of `count($watchList)`?

Comment: Do `saveProduct` or `getProductDetail` modify `$watchList` in any way?

Comment: 288 items

if i comment the function call and only echo out the following line after function I see all the iterations outputed.

Comment: getProductDetail is returning an array and saveProduct is executing SQL on MySql DB. saveProduct takes argument of associative array.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the array is not sequential. You're assuming that it goes from 0-n, but that might not be the case. Use this and it should work:

```
echo '<ol>';
foreach($watchList as $key=>$watchItem){
    saveProduct(getProductDetail($watchItem));
    echo ' <li>Product Saved '. $watchItem .'</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem with the loop. Must be something wrong with the functions you're calling.

Try turning on error reporting if you haven't already.

```
ini_set(‘error_reporting’, E_ALL);
ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Add code above to your code to see what's wrong?

```
foreach($watchList as $value){
    saveProduct(getProductDetail($value));
    echo ' <li>Product Saved '. $value .'</li>';

}
```

Comment: the astonishing thing is that in result of first iteration the data get saved in db but loop fails

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array key is not matching the value of $i in each iteration of the loop, presumably because your array keys are not sequential integers.  No doubt the output (when you take the function call out) just prints 'Product Saved' as the $watchList[$i] is NULL.

You are simply trying to pass the value in the array to that function, so do it as follows and it won't matter what the keys are;

```
echo '<ol>';
foreach($watchlist as $key => $item){
    saveProduct(getProductDetail($item));
    echo ' <li>Product Saved '. $item .'</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```